# How to get instagram media metrics ? Cannot get any media info using ig media id, Instagram graph api

Tags: rest, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I have created different API queries on searching hashtags and searching recent media with that. This all works fine. but when I grab the ID from media objects from the recent_media query and try to query them separately since then I'm able to query more data. It won't work.

[https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/ig_hashtag_search?access_token={token}&user_id={user_id}&q=hashtag_name](https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/ig_hashtag_search?access_token=%7Btoken%7D&user_id=%7Buser_id%7D&q=hashtag_name)

This returns

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": "17843780662045901"
    }
]
```

Then I query

[https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/17843780662045901/recent_media?access_token={token}&user_id={user_id}&fields=id,media_url](https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/17843780662045901/recent_media?access_token=%7Btoken%7D&user_id=%7Buser_id%7D&fields=id,media_url)

with result

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": "17939405797365335"
    },
    {
        "id": "17868693508835640"
    },
```

and then I try to access media with
**"get graph.facebook.com/{graph-api-version}/ig_media_id?fields=id,username"** endpoint

I get

```
{'error': 
        {'message': "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '17930129249499764' does not 
         exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at 
         https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api", 'type': 'GraphMethodException', 
        'code': 100, 'error_subcode': 33, 'fbtrace_id': 'A0mF0lmOv0VzfO-dN6NTTFA'}}
```

Following permissions granted at standard access level to my facebook ap:

```
    'instagram_basic',
    'pages_show_list',
    'pages_read_engagement'
```

What is the source of problem?

And Is there an alternative wethod to get owner username of an media from media id or media_url using graph api?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-hashtag/recent-media#reading: _"- You cannot request the username field on returned media objects. - Responses will not include any personally identifiable information."_

Comment: Yes it gives an authentication error. Howewer username field on media object edge is public as stated here [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media#:~:text=UTC%20%C2%B100%3A00).-,username,-Public)

Comment: get graph.facebook.com/{graph-api-version}/ig_media_id?fields=id,username  this api can only get media detail with the media user's access token,   You can not get other's media with your token.